# Apache server spam post requests

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, joomla

I really don`t know how to describe this problem but i got screenshot.

[image]

black = server IP
blue = domain

I also noticed some strange files in "mak/administrator" folder.

[image]

Any suggestion?

p.s this site is Joomla

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is the problem? What else have you done to try to fix? Are you running the latest version of Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the source of any of these files?

This could be some malicious code.

Do you have any Anti-Virus or software you use to check for Malware/Tojans?